# ReplaceWith XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xelement

Below is the snippet of content of my XDocument .

```
    <p style="">
            <img id="Object3"  src="Object3_png16malpha.png" width="78" height="37" />
    </p>
    <p style="">
        <span>1 point: correct response of Point </span>X: 
        <img id="Object4"  src="Object4_png16malpha.png" width="76" height="37" /> Point y: 
        <img id="Object5"  src="Object5_png16malpha.png" width="78" height="37" /> Point z: 
        <img id="Object6"  src="Object6_png16malpha.png" width="78" height="37" />. 
        <span style="">(1 point).</span>
    </p>
<accessElement identifier="1234">
    <contentLinkInfo LinkIdentifierRef="9_BEGIN" type="Text">
        <objectLink />
    </contentLinkInfo>
</accessElement>
```

Basically I am trying to replace each image `<img>` tag with new content. For image `<Tag>` of Object3 looks as below after processing.

```
<span class="mathml" data-png="Object3_png16malpha.png" data-svg="Object3_png16malpha.svg">
    <img id="Object3" alt="" src="Object3_png16malpha.png" />
</span>
```

But below is the **output** I am getting which skips processing of some of image tags which I am not sure about.

```
<p style="">
        <span class="mathml" data-png="Object3_png16malpha.png" data-svg="Object3_png16malpha.svg">
            <img id="Object3" alt="" src="Object3_png16malpha.png" />
    </span>
</p>
<p style="">
    <span>1 point: correct response of Point </span>X: 
    <span class="mathml" data-png="Object4_png16malpha.png" data-svg="Object4_png16malpha.svg">
        <img id="Object4" alt="" src="Object4_png16malpha.png" />
    </span> Point y: 
    <img id="Object5"  src="Object5_png16malpha.png" width="78" height="37" /> Point z: 
    <img id="Object6"  src="Object6_png16malpha.png" width="78" height="37" />. 
    <span style="">(1 point).</span>
</p>
<accessElement identifier="1234">
    <contentLinkInfo LinkIdentifierRef="9_BEGIN" type="Text">
        <objectLink />
    </contentLinkInfo>
</accessElement>
```

Below is snippet of my code

```
  foreach (XElement bodyElement in uthDocument.Descendants().Elements())
        {
            if (bodyElement.Name == "img")
            {
                XElement newImageElement = getNewImageElement(bodyElement);
                bodyElement.ReplaceWith(newImageElement);
            }

        }
```

My code does skips the replacement of last two image elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of LINQ to XML Is akin to a linked list - each node holds a reference to its next node.

When you replace your original `bodyElement` with your new one, then the next node pointed to by `bodyElement` is now `null` as you've pulled it out of the tree.  So, most likely, one of your iterators will then break and return at this point.

As an aside, you also don't need your `Elements()` call, as you'll end up iterating most elements more than once.  `Descendants()` will return all elements below already.

So, just eagerly evaluate `Descendants()` and iterate that instead:

```
foreach (XElement bodyElement in uthDocument.Descendants().ToList())
{
    ...
}
```

Ideally you'd filter this before calling `ToList()`.  Assuming this is XHTML this is fairly simple:

```
XNamespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
var imgElements = uthDocument.Descendants(xhtml + "img").ToList();
```